# Characterization of quadratic polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory

This is a nice question which I'd like to share with everyone.

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ be a function s.t. for each $a \in (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times},$ the function $f(x+a)-f(x)$ is a bijection. Prove that $f$ is a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: Were you going to share your own solution?

Comment: @Hurkyl: sure, if I find one :) sometimes when I come across a *nice* question which I have no clue, I jump and post it in MSE. You may find some of them in my recent posts.

Comment: Where does this question come from? What's the context? Is it from a book or paper?

Comment: @DonAntonio: my friend told me a while ago. I will ask him, when I find him.

Comment: See [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/135949/6085).